# How to substring a text in sql-server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to get first name, last name in the query from text like:

```
'answer for the question number №2355, Ivan Fomin, nds doens't work'
```

but the text can be in a different format smt like:

```
'answer for the question number №2355, nds doens't work, Ivan Fomin'
```

or:

```
'answer IVAn FOMIN for the question number №2355, nds doens't work'
```

Is there any way to get that result?
Result should be: `Ivan Fomin`.

Comment: If there is no set pattern, I have a doubt if you would ever be able to fetch the correct name.

Comment: How do you know what the name on the above is? Yes, "Ivan Fomin" looks like a name, but how do *you* know that the name isn't "question number"? There has to be some logic to be able to determine where in the string the name is. If there is none, you have no chance (especially with SQL).

Comment: Is there a given finite group of names? If so, you could check every word to see if it exists in this group.

Comment: Required link: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: I solved that question in oracle by using patters with regexp substr and I got error result.  I came to conclusions that I need to create a dictionary of names and join it with result of regexp substr to get current result. So, the problem is that I didn’t find an analogue regexp substr in SQL server. Would you help me with it?

Comment: Is there any way to do that without using patindex and substring?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to get the solution on this, but please keep in mind the SQL Server doesn't know which are nouns, pronouns, verbs, adjectives...

I have created one temp table i.e `"#TEMP"` and insert only Fixed words, the data look like this,

`SELECT * FROM #TEMP`

```
ID  FixWords
1   ?2355
2   answer
3   doesn't
4   for
5   nds
6   number
7   question
8   the
9   work
```

---

if your text has fixed characters and only the "Name" of the person will get change every time then the following solution will be work for you.

```
DECLARE @STR NVARCHAR(MAX)='answer for the question number №2355, Ivan Fomin, nds doens''t work' -- Your Text
   DECLARE @COUNT INT
   DECLARE @ID INT =1
   SET @COUNT = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM #TEMP)

   WHILE (@ID <= @COUNT)
   BEGIN
   SELECT @STR =  LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(@STR,FIXWORDS,''),',',''))) 
                  FROM #TEMP WHERE ID = @ID

    SET @ID =@ID +1

    END

    PRINT @STR
   
    --Output  Ivan Fomin
```